# ¿Cómo calcular el producto escalar entre dos ArrayLists redefinidas?

Tags: java, matemáticas

Quiero crear un método que calcule el producto escalar `scalar` entre dos vectores representados por la clase `safeList`, modificados desde la clase `ArrayList`.

Sin embargo cuando intento crear la matriz de resultados, no puedo obtener el tamaño de las matrices que se multiplicarán. Esto a pesar del método `size()` para el tamaño.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;


class MySafeList extends ArrayList<Double>{

    static ArrayList<Double> mySafeList;

    synchronized public boolean add(Double d){
        mySafeList.add(d);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int size(){
        return mySafeList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Double get(int i){
        return mySafeList.get(i);

    }

    MySafeList scalar(MySafeList v1, MySafeList v2){
        //permet de calculer le produit scalaire entre deux vecteurs
        double[] result = new double[v1.size()];
        for(int i=0 ; i<v1.size() ; i++) {
            result[i] = v1[i]*v2[i];
        }
        return result;
    }

    MySafeList randomScalarTest(MySafeList arrayRandom1, MySafeList arrayRandom2){

        Random rand = new Random();
        rand.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
        n = arrayRandom1.size();
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            Integer r = rand.nextInt() % 256;
            arrayRandom1.add(r); // problema : no es doble
            arrayRandom2.add(r); // tambien
        }

        return scalar(arrayRandom1,arrayRandom2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySafeList safeList1 = new MySafeList();
        MySafeList safeList2 = new MySafeList();

        safeList1.add(2.0);
        safeList1.add(3.0);
        safeList1.add(4.0);

        safeList2.add(1.0);
        safeList2.add(3.0);
        safeList2.add(5.0);

        scalar(safeList1,safeList2);

        ArrayList<Integer> arrayRandom1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayRandom2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(n);    

    }

}
```

El terminal me devuelve:

```
(booenv) C:\Users\antoi\Documents\Programming\Julien\TD6_multi_threading>javac MySafeList.java
MySafeList.java:52: error: array required, but MySafeList found
                    result[i] = v1[i]*v2[i];
                                  ^
MySafeList.java:52: error: array required, but MySafeList found
                    result[i] = v1[i]*v2[i];
                                        ^
MySafeList.java:54: error: incompatible types: double[] cannot be converted to MySafeList
                return result;
                       ^
MySafeList.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
                n = arrayRandom1.size();
                ^
  symbol:   variable n
  location: class MySafeList
MySafeList.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
                for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
                                ^
  symbol:   variable n
  location: class MySafeList
MySafeList.java:65: error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to Double
                    arrayRandom1.add(r);
                                     ^
MySafeList.java:66: error: incompatible types: Integer cannot be converted to Double
                    arrayRandom2.add(r);
                                     ^
MySafeList.java:84: error: non-static method scalar(MySafeList,MySafeList) cannot be referenced from a static context
                scalar(safeList1,safeList2);
                ^
Note: MySafeList.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
8 errors
```

Comment: ¿Que quieres decir con "no puedo obtener su tamaño de la matriz de entrada"? Aparte `result[i] = v1[i]*v2[i];` te puede dar una excepción si v2 es de menor tamaño que v1

Comment: @JDev Me disculpe, me he exprimido mal. Quiero decir que no puedo obtener los tamaños de `v1` mientras que utilizo el método `size()` de `MySafeList`. Anadi las errores que me contesta el terminal.

Comment: Tenés muchos errores conceptuales: Al extender de ArrayList<Double> tu clase ya es un ArrayList<Double> con get() y size(), no hace falta el override de estos métodos. El atributo static mySafeList no tiene sentido y te complica lo que querés lograr, me parece que lo querés usar en lugar de `this`. El método del calculo del producto escalar tiene la forma de un método estático de clase, pero está declarado como un método de instancia que no actúa sobre si msmo. Y finalmente estás queriendo acceder a los valores del ArrayList como si fueran vectores ([i] en lugar de get(i)).